# Google Maps Isn't Showing Zoom Icons

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps app on my Chrome Desktop Machine.

I use the native Google Maps app that's installed but it seems to be acting strange in that I don't have any zoom in and out icons? It's as if it thinks I can pinch the screen like you would in a tablet or phone but this is a Chromebook and I use a mouse and keyboard

Any help you can offer please to get the zoom icons on the map like normal would be appreciated

Many thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJksJ.jpg)

I didn't know what to try to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

So I noticed that I had "Google Maps" installed and then just "maps".

I have uninstalled "maps" and now use "Google Maps" and it seems to have fixed the issue. I'm not sure what the other app was but it obviously wasn't the Google Maps one that worked

Thanks anyway

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).